Tight subplot axes without their plot to the figure
I have made a subplot in matplotlib and managed to to put the different cmap I have on the same column. For a minimal working example (with dummy cmaps):
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate sample data
data1 = np.random.rand(10, 10)
data2 = np.random.rand(10, 10)
data3 = np.random.rand(10, 10)

fig_bandwidth = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
ax1 = plt.subplot(3, 2, 6)
ax2 = plt.subplot(3, 2, 4)
ax3 = plt.subplot(3, 2, 2)
ax_bandwidth = plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
axes = [ax1, ax2, ax3]

# Plot data and add color bars
for ax, data in zip(axes, [data1, data2, data3]):
    cax = ax_bandwidth.imshow(data, aspect='auto', cmap='viridis')
    plt.colorbar(cax, ax=ax)
    ax.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


What I am trying to do is have a tight subplot with the figure on the left and the 3 color bars on the right in the same column, but it seems the plotting boxes are still there, preventing me from placing these axes next to the figure. Maybe using subplots isn't the best solution, any suggestion?
Then how could I place an ax title spanning across the three color bars since they represent the same thing (bandwidth in MHz for context).

Do you have the complete code linked to some repo? Someone else might be able to solve this issue with the minimal sample, but having the cmaps and everything else would help in replicating the issue.

@M.A. Yes but it'd be too tedious to go through it, I've updated the minimal working example to include some dummy color bars

Using add_axes works much better than sublots. It gives me much more freedom on the placement.
Here is a minimal working example with dummy cbars:
fig_bandwidth = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
# Creating three axes: add_axes([xmin,ymin,dx,dy])
ax1 = fig_bandwidth.add_axes((0.75, 0.05, 0.1, 0.3))
ax2 = fig_bandwidth.add_axes((0.75, 0.36, 0.1, 0.3))
ax3 = fig_bandwidth.add_axes((0.75, 0.67, 0.1, 0.3))
ax_bandwidth = fig_bandwidth.add_axes((0.1, 0.05, 0.7, 0.92))
axes = [ax1, ax2, ax3]
# Generate sample data
data1 = np.random.rand(10, 10)
data2 = np.random.rand(10, 10)
data3 = np.random.rand(10, 10)
for ax, data in zip(axes, [data1, data2, data3]):
    cax = ax_bandwidth.imshow(data, aspect='auto', cmap='viridis')
    plt.colorbar(cax, ax=ax)
    ax.axis('off')
plt.show()


Another option is to set up the subplots using subplot_mosaic.  Note that I pass the axes to colorbar via the cax parameter instead of ax, so it is used directly rather than creating a new axes by "stealing" space from ax.  I also set the aspect ratio manually to 20, since 20 is the default when colorbar creates a new axes.
supylabel can be used to add a label for the righthand three axes.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate sample data
data1 = np.random.rand(10, 10)
data2 = np.random.rand(10, 10)
data3 = np.random.rand(10, 10)

mosaic = """
AB
AC
AD
"""

fig_bandwidth, ax_dict = plt.subplot_mosaic(mosaic, figsize=(12, 6), width_ratios=(8, 1))
ax_bandwidth = ax_dict['A']

# Plot data and add color bars
for key, data in zip('BCD', [data1, data2, data3]):
    im = ax_bandwidth.imshow(data, aspect='auto', cmap='viridis')
    cbar_ax = ax_dict[key]
    cbar_ax.set_aspect(20)
    plt.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax)
    
fig_bandwidth.supylabel('Bandwidth', x=0.98)
    
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


